# Lighweight tool to monitor elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search 90.02 version and I am looking for a tool that can give me simple metrics like cluster health check, memory, os stats as described by [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html)over time so that I can accumulate them and fine tune elasticsearch performance. 
A list of tools are mentioned here at [elasticsearch docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/community/current/health.html)
but my exact use case is just metrics on a remote machine over time. I do not want any fancy ui's but a accumulative data over time with simple ui. Can you please suggest something by experience?

Answer (score 0):

The list of Elasticsearch plugins within the docs is a comprehensive one. I have used the first four plugins mentioned, and they each have their own pro's and con's. I believe [Marvel](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/marvel/), a tool written by Elasticsearch developers, will fulfil your requirements of viewing your cluster state over time. Depending on the activity on your cluster this can utilise a lot of disk space.

Marvel has a fantastic UI, which may not fulfil your requirements for something simplistic. It is free to use outside of production, but not so in production, this may be a deal breaker for you use case. Otherwise, I am aware of no other options. Perhaps a custom application to carry these task out for you may appeal to you more, periodically collecting the data from ES API and storing these yourself.

Comment: The Marvel link is incorrect, it leads to x-pack monitoring. The correct one is https://www.elastic.co/downloads/marvel